# Swift array.append() not working as expected

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, append

I'm new to Swift and can't seem to get this append method working, any help would be appreciated!

Here are my models and view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var gameInformation: GameInformation
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Button("Append") {
                let index = gameInformation.sets.firstIndex(of: gameInformation.sets.last!)
                gameInformation.sets[index!].legs.append(Leg())
                print(gameInformation.sets[index!].legs)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(gameInformation: .constant(GameInformation()))
    }
}

struct GameInformation: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    var sets: [Set] = [Set()]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case id, sets
     }
}

struct Set: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    static func == (lhs: Set, rhs: Set) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var legs: [Leg] = []
}

struct Leg: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString

    var playerOneScores: [Int] = []
    var playerTwoScores: [Int] = []
}
```

As you can see I have a parent GameInformation model, this has `sets` which is an array of `Set`, and then `Set` has `legs` which is an array of `Leg`, the button in the content view simply adds a new `Leg` but when the value of `gameInformation.sets[index!].legs` is printed, there's only one entry which is the initialised value.

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Have you tried adding a print statement before appending to check that it actually has a value?

Comment: It's not a good idea to name a custom type the same as a built in type so you should change Set to something else.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but your use of `!` when access the elements/indexes of the array is potentially dangerous and can lead to crashes -- you may want to consider refactoring to a more robust/safer approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written an implementation of `Equatable` on `Set` (which I've renamed to `MySet` -- see the comments for why) that is getting in your way. Right now, your implementation tells SwiftUI that the elements are equal if the `id` property is the same. So, if the `legs` change, SwiftUI doesn't bother updating, because it thinks that the elements are still the same.

Instead, you can remove your custom `Equatable` conformance and make `Leg` `Equatable` as well.

```
struct GameInformation: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    var sets: [MySet] = [MySet()] //<-- Renamed
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case id, sets
     }
}

struct MySet: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable { //<-- Satisfies Equatable because all of its properties are Equatable
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var legs: [Leg] = []
}

struct Leg: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable { //<-- Marked as Equatable as well
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString

    var playerOneScores: [Int] = []
    var playerTwoScores: [Int] = []
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Makes perfect sense now that you have said it, I appreciate your help